# Why is my jQuery variable empty?

Tags: jquery, variables, scoping

I am new to jQuery and I ran into a problem that is probably easy to spot for most of the frontend gurus out here.

I created the following script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#facet_properties input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            var queryString = getQueryString();
            $('body').load(window.location.pathname.concat(queryString));
        })
    });
});

function getQueryString() {
    var queryString = "";
    var queryStringBegun = false;
    $("#facet_properties input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var checkboxFullName = $(this).attr('name');
            var checkboxName = checkboxFullName.substr(checkboxFullName.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
            var concatenationCharacter = '&';
            if (!queryStringBegun) {
                concatenationCharacter = '?';
            }
            queryString.concat(concatenationCharacter).concat(checkboxName);
            queryStringBegun = true;
        }
    });

    return queryString;
}
```

I am trying to create a query string variable in the getQueryString method, but somehow queryString stays empty. When a checkbox is checked I see the statement queryString.concat(concatenationCharacter).concat(checkboxName); is reached and I see that 'concetenationCharacter' and 'checkboxName' have the correct value. So why does my function return ""?

This is probably a variable scoping issue or something. I am guessing it's something simple. Thanks!

Comment: can you rename one of the var queryString to var queryString2 or something and try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concat()` doesn't alter the original string. You have to assign the return value back to the variable: `queryString = queryString.concat(concatenationCharacter).concat(checkboxName);`

Using `concat()` is a bit of an overkill, though: you can concatenate strings simply with the `+` operator:

```
queryString += concatenationCharacter + checkboxName;
```

Not related to the problem, but you can shorten the code you have by moving the `.is(':checked')` check from the function to the selector:

```
$("#facet_properties input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
    ...
```

You also don't need to attach the click event to each element individually. You can again just use the selector. Using a variable in the event is also a bit unnecessary (unless you have more use for it in the actual app).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#facet_properties input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
        $('body').load(window.location.pathname + getQueryString() );
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, a big D'OH would be in place here. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I will use the :checked selector. Didn't know that was possible. I used the queryString variable for debugging purposes earlier. Will remove that as well. Thanks a mill.

Answer (score 1):

concat() returns a value....

collect that value ...
line `queryString.concat(concatenationCharacter).concat(checkboxName);`

should be something like this

```
queryString = queryString.concat(concatenationCharacter).concat(checkboxName);
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested it, but I think I would do something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#facet_properties input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            var checkboxFullName = $(this).attr('name');
            var checkboxName = checkboxFullName.substr(checkboxFullName.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
            var concatenationCharacter = '&';
            if (!queryStringBegun) {
                concatenationCharacter = '?';
            }
            var queryString.concat(concatenationCharacter).concat(checkboxName);
            $('body').load(window.location.pathname.concat(queryString));
        })
    });
});
```

As I said, I have not tested it